# ActiveModel::Serializer include attribute prefix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, active-model-serializers

I am using AMS to comply with an older API and attempting to include a prefix on each attribute.

Suppose i have this serializer:

```
InvoiceSerializer.new(invoice).serializable_hash
=> {
 :id=>662473,
 :number=>"3817",
 :created_at=>Tue, 27 Jan 2015 14:55:51 PST -08:00,
 :updated_at=>Tue, 27 Jan 2015 14:56:20 PST -08:00,
 :date=>Tue, 27 Jan 2015,
 :subtotal=>#<BigDecimal:7fa89e051380,'0.1E3',9(18)>,
 :total=>#<BigDecimal:7fa89e050f70,'0.1095E3',18(18)>,
 :tax=>#<BigDecimal:7fa89e050d40,'0.95E1',18(18)>,
 :verified_paid=>false,
 :tech_marked_paid=>true,
 :ticket_id=>11111
}
```

and would like the output to be:

```
InvoiceSerializer.new(invoice).serializable_hash
=> {
 :invoice_id=>662473,
 :invoice_number=>"3817",
 :invoice_created_at=>Tue, 27 Jan 2015 14:55:51 PST -08:00,
 :invoice_updated_at=>Tue, 27 Jan 2015 14:56:20 PST -08:00,
 :invoice_date=>Tue, 27 Jan 2015,
 :invoice_subtotal=>#<BigDecimal:7fa89e051380,'0.1E3',9(18)>,
 :invoice_total=>#<BigDecimal:7fa89e050f70,'0.1095E3',18(18)>,
 :invoice_tax=>#<BigDecimal:7fa89e050d40,'0.95E1',18(18)>,
 :invoice_verified_paid=>false,
 :invoice_tech_marked_paid=>true,
 :invoice_ticket_id=>11111
}
```

I would prefer to not metaprogram a solution as other people will be using this and I don't want them to hate me.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4 adds a handy [`Hash#transform_keys`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-transform_keys) method that makes this particularly easy.

```
class InvoiceSerializer
  # ...
  KEY_PREFIX = "invoice_"

  def serializable_hash(*args)
    hash = super
    hash.transform_keys {|key| :"#{KEY_PREFIX}#{key}" }
  end
end
```

If you're stuck with Rails 3, it's easy to do the same thing without `transform_keys`:

```
def serializable_hash(*args)
  hash = super

  hash.each_with_object({}) do |(key, val), result|
    result[:"#{KEY_PREFIX}#{key}"] = val
  end
end
```

Comment: `transform_keys` is only available in rails4

Comment: I assumed you were using Rails 4 (it was released almost two years ago) since you didn't specify otherwise. I've updated my answer with a version that works without `transform_keys`.

Answer (score 0):

`transform_keys` only works in rails 4. Rails3 solution would be to reimplement transform_keys :)

[source](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.1.8/Hash/transform_keys)

```
# File activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/keys.rb, line 8
  def transform_keys
    result = {}
    each_key do |key|
      result[yield(key)] = self[key]
    end
    result
  end
```

and inside serializer would be:

```
class InvoiceSerializer
  # ...
  KEY_PREFIX = "invoice_"

  def serializable_hash(*args)
    hash = super
    result = {}
    hash.each_key {|key| result["#{KEY_PREFIX}#{key}"] = hash[key] }
    result
  end
end
```